# Count checked checkboxes in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have several checkboxes and a button inside a GridView.

I need count the checkboxes selected and update with this number of checkboxes selected the field counter of the doTable DB MySQL.

I tried this solution but for the checkboxes selected I have this output in update, e.g. 3 checkboxes selected.

```
counter
1
2
3
```

How to do for this output?

```
counter
3
3
3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox);

        if (chkRow.Checked)
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
            UpdateProduct(counter);

        }
    }


private void UpdateProduct(int counter)
{
    string sql = String.Format(@"Update doTable set 
                                 counter = {0}; ",
                                 counter.ToString());
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }      
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you try to run the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to update the rows with the total-count? Then calculate the total-count first:

```
int totalCount = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Count(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked);
// maybe: if(totalCount > 0)
UpdateProduct(totalCount);
```

Note that you don't need the `foreach` at all with this approach.

You need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to postpone your call to `UpdateProduct`. You're calling it too soon. Try this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
    CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox);

    if (chkRow.Checked) {
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}

// Call this now.
UpdateProduct(counter);
```